# UserWarning: Label not :NUMBER: is present in all training examples

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I am doing multilabel classification, where I try to predict correct labels for each document and here is my code:

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
X = dataframe['body'].values 
y = mlb.fit_transform(dataframe['tag'].values)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, 
                                   stop_words='english', 
                                   max_df = 0.8, 
                                   min_df = 10)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])

predicted = cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y)
```

When running my code I get multiple warnings:

```
UserWarning: Label not :NUMBER: is present in all training examples.
```

When I print out predicted and true labels, cca half of all documents has it's predictions for labels empty.

Why is this happening, is it related to warnings it prints out while training is running? How can I avoid those empty predictions?

---

**EDIT01:**
This is also happening when using other estimators than `LinearSVC()`.

I've tried `RandomForestClassifier()` and it gives empty predictions as well. Strange thing is, when I use `cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y, method='predict_proba')` for predicting probabilities for each label, instead of binary decisions 0/1, there is always at least one label per predicted set with probability > 0 for given document. So I dont know why is this label not chosen with binary decisioning? Or is binary decisioning evaluated in different way than probabilities?

**EDIT02:**
I have found an old [post](http://scikit-learn-general.narkive.com/lm8imv9z/linearsvc-somtimes-returns-no-label) where OP was dealing with similar problem. Is this the same case?

Comment: You should share full code which you used in predict and fit

Comment: `cross_val_predict` is calling those methods implicitly, I am using `Pipeline` approach. This is full code. I have only used `MultiLabelBinarizer` for transofming y labels into binary vectors before feeding them into method `cross_val_predict`.

Comment: Oh yes. I overlooked that you are using `cross_val_predict`. Show some samples of X and y

Comment: @VivekKumar sure, Q should be now complete.

Comment: It looks like your assumption was correct with your second edit. The developers very clearly stated that returning nothing is a desired behavior if your data suffers from the class imbalance problem. Can you input a logging statement in the `decision_function` you are using to see if your data is simply a poor fit for your classifier? If so, you may have to augment your decision function to control what level of a fit you desire.

Comment: @karnesJ.R Thanks for response. What do you mean by logging statement please? Do you want output of the [decision_function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function)?

Comment: Can you upload dataset?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why is this happening, is it related to warnings it prints out while training is running?

The issue is likely to be that some tags occur just in a few documents (check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342122/python-sklearn-multilabel-classification-userwarning-label-not-226-is-present) for details). When you split the dataset into train and test to validate your model, it may happen that some tags are missing from the training data. Let `train_indices` be an array with the indices of the training samples. If a particular tag (of index `k`) does not occur in the training sample, all the elements in the `k`-th column of the indicator matrix `y[train_indices]` are zeros.

> How can I avoid those empty predictions?

In the scenario described above the classifier will not be able to reliably predict the `k`-th tag in the test documents (more on this in the next paragraph). Therefore you cannot trust the predictions made by `clf.predict` and you need to implement the prediction function on your own, for example by using the decision values returned by `clf.decision_function` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561554/scikit-learn-label-not-x-is-present-in-all-training-examples/34561760#34561760).

> So I don't know why is this label not chosen with binary decisioning? Or is binary decisioning evaluated in different way than probabilities?

In datasets containing many labels the occurrence frequency for most of them uses to be rather low. If these low values are fed to a binary classifier (i.e. a classifier that makes a 0-1 prediction) it is highly probable that the classifier would pick 0 for all tags on all documents.

> I have found an old post where OP was dealing with similar problem. Is this the same case?

Yes, absolutely. That guy is facing exactly the same problem as you and his code is pretty similar to yours.

---

***Demo***

To further explain the issue I have elaborated a simple toy example using mock data.

```
Q = {'What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?': ['python'],
     'What is a metaclass in Python?': ['oop'],
     'How do I check whether a file exists using Python?': ['python'],
     'How to make a chain of function decorators?': ['python', 'decorator'],
     'Using i and j as variables in Matlab': ['matlab', 'naming-conventions'],
     'MATLAB: get variable type': ['matlab'],
     'Why is MATLAB so fast in matrix multiplication?': ['performance'],
     'Is MATLAB OOP slow or am I doing something wrong?': ['matlab-oop'],
    }
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'body': Q.keys(), 'tag': Q.values()})    

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
X = dataframe['body'].values 
y = mlb.fit_transform(dataframe['tag'].values)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(lowercase=True, 
                                   stop_words='english', 
                                   max_df=0.8, 
                                   min_df=1)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC()))])
```

Please, notice that I have set `min_df=1` since my dataset is much smaller than yours. When I run the following sentence:

```
predicted = cross_val_predict(classifier, X, y)
```

I get a bunch of warnings

```
C:\...\multiclass.py:76: UserWarning: Label not 4 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))
C:\\multiclass.py:76: UserWarning: Label not 0 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))
C:\...\multiclass.py:76: UserWarning: Label not 3 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))
C:\...\multiclass.py:76: UserWarning: Label not 5 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))
C:\...\multiclass.py:76: UserWarning: Label not 2 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))
```

and the following prediction:

```
In [5]: np.set_printoptions(precision=2, threshold=1000)    

In [6]: predicted
Out[6]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Those rows whose entries are all `0` indicate that no tag is predicted for the corresponding document.

---

***Workaround***

For the sake of the analysis, let us validate the model manually rather than through `cross_val_predict`.

```
import warnings
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit

rs = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=.5, random_state=0)
train_indices, test_indices = rs.split(X).next()

with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as received_warnings:
    warnings.simplefilter("always")
    X_train, y_train = X[train_indices], y[train_indices]
    X_test, y_test = X[test_indices], y[test_indices]
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predicted_test = classifier.predict(X_test)
    for w in received_warnings:
        print w.message
```

When the snippet above is executed two warnings are issued (I used a context manager to make sure warnings are catched):

```
Label not 2 is present in all training examples.
Label not 4 is present in all training examples.
```

This is consistent with the fact that tags of indices `2` and `4` are missing from the training samples:

```
In [40]: y_train
Out[40]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

For some documents, the prediction is empty (those documents corresponding to the rows with all zeros in `predicted_test`):

```
In [42]: predicted_test
Out[42]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

To overcome that issue, you could implement your own prediction function like this:

```
def get_best_tags(clf, X, lb, n_tags=3):
    decfun = clf.decision_function(X)
    best_tags = np.argsort(decfun)[:, :-(n_tags+1): -1]
    return lb.classes_[best_tags]
```

By doing so, each document is always assigned the `n_tag` tags with the highest confidence score:

```
In [59]: mlb.inverse_transform(predicted_test)
Out[59]: [('matlab',), (), (), ('matlab', 'naming-conventions')]

In [60]: get_best_tags(classifier, X_test, mlb)
Out[60]: 
array([['matlab', 'oop', 'matlab-oop'],
       ['oop', 'matlab-oop', 'matlab'],
       ['oop', 'matlab-oop', 'matlab'],
       ['matlab', 'naming-conventions', 'oop']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same error. Then I used *LabelEncoder()* instead of *MultiLabelBinarizer()* to encode the labels.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(Labels)
```

I am not getting that error anymore.