# Python: Scikit Learn MLPClassifier error when putting in Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using a `OneVsRestClassifier` on `MLPClassifier`. I am using this for classifying text data where `X` is set of questions in `pd.DataFrame` and `Y` is multi-label and multi-class strings. Please see below the code snippets

```
text_clf = Pipeline([('scale',StandardScaler(with_mean=False)),('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(MLPClassifier(learning_rate = 'adaptive', solver = 'lbfgs',random_state=9000)))])
parameters = {'clf__alpha':[10.0 ** ~ np.arange(1, 7).any()],'clf__hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,),(50,)],'clf__max_iter': [1000,500],'clf__activation':('relu','tanh')}
grid = GridSearchCV(text_clf, parameters, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, scoring= 'accuracy') 
with parallel_backend('threading'):
    grid.fit(X,Y)
```

I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter activation for estimator OneVsRestClassifier(estimator=MLPClassifier(activation='relu', alpha=0.0001, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9,
   beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08,
   hidden_layer_sizes=(100,), learning_rate='adaptive',
   learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=200, momentum=0.9,
   n_iter_no_change=10, nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5,
   random_state=9000, shuffle=True, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001,
   validation_fraction=0.1, verbose=False, warm_start=False),
      n_jobs=None). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

As per my understanding `MLPClassifier` supports Multi Label classification. Is it indicating that `parameters` need to be re-examined? If so, then can any body please give any clue on where to make changes in `parameters`?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MLPClassifier` is nested into `OneVsRestClassifier` as its estimator.

In other words, `parameters` should specify that all of `alpha`, `hidden_layer_sizes`, ... are meant for nested estimator not `OneVsRestClassifier`.

Changing your `parameters` like following should do the job:

```
parameters = {'clf__estimator__alpha':[10.0 ** ~ np.arange(1,7).any()],
    'clf__estimator__hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,),(50,)],
    'clf__estimator__max_iter': [1000,500],
    'clf__estimator__activation':('relu','tanh')}
```

Comment: Thanks C.Kim. However, it is giving an user warning as `UserWarning: Label not 42 is present in all training examples.
  str(classes[c]))`. Any clue why such warning is coming?

Comment: @pythondumb From the look of it, it seems like there is a problem with `x` for `grid.fit`. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821315/userwarning-label-not-number-is-present-in-all-training-examples can help you out :)

Comment: Thanks a ton!! let me use Labelencoder and see how this work